# how to find max value in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of the dictionary:

```
 my_list = [
    {
     'name': 'Angela',
     'bid': 130
    },
    {
    'name': 'James',
    'bid': 145
    }, 
    {
    'name': 'Jane',
    'bid': 115
    }
    ]
```

What I would like to be able to do is return the maximum value of capacity and `print(f"The Winner is {name} with a bid of {bid}")`

Answer (score 1):

```
max(my_list, key=lambda x:x['bid'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `max` function here

```
my_list = [{'name': 'Angela','bid': 130},{'name': 'James','bid': 145},{'name': 'Jane','bid': 115}]
max_data = max(my_list, key= lambda x:x['bid'])
name, bid = max_data['name'], max_data['bid']
print(f"The Winner is {name} with a bid of {bid}")
```

output

```
The Winner is James with a bid of 145
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `format` method so it looks up the keys for me:

```
winner = max(my_list, key=lambda x: x['bid'])
print("The Winner is {name} with a bid of {bid}".format(**winner))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5RC4IwEADg9/2Ko5epSCQWhOBDrz0HPYjExJkjN2UOVMTfvtZcEdE93HHHfdx1k6pbER87qTWfbg3rFaSQITAx2wxYEE5xAvgk7rQhOHTjgpVmGsU72y/hl/mQs6m9E2@wPzgA/4WgPyBywOYcoYEJQaV5k5PRc0@H8KBT2hBelATGBMbM6txHnWRCeZtLTeG6QtbD/Dq3wMBUDQTMJrQVzKYum23VSk6UFwTrHd/X@gk)